# Buscar en una lista en dart con where

Tags: flutter, dart

En la librería PhoneField, a la cual le quiero hacer algunas modificaciones, tengo una lista de paises de este estilo:

```
const List<Country> countries = [
  Country(
    name: "Afghanistan",
    flag: "",
    code: "AF",
    dialCode: "93",
    minLength: 9,
    maxLength: 9,
  ),
  Country(
    name: "Åland Islands",
    flag: "",
    code: "AX",
    dialCode: "358",
    minLength: 15,
    maxLength: 15,
  ),
  Country(
    name: "Albania",
    flag: "",
    code: "AL",
    dialCode: "355",
    minLength: 9,
    maxLength: 9,
  ),
  Country(
    name: "Algeria",
    flag: "",
    code: "DZ",
    dialCode: "213",
    minLength: 9,
    maxLength: 9,
  ),
  Country(
    name: "American Samoa",
    flag: "",
    code: "AS",
    dialCode: "1684",
    minLength: 7,
    maxLength: 7,
  ),
....
];
```

Entonces, dado un "dialCode", quiero obtener el pais para dicho dial code, para ello estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
_selectedCountry = countries.firstWhere((item) => initialDialCode == item.dialCode);
```

Sin embargo, debe estar mal, ya que no devuelve nada, pero tampoco devuelve ningún error...
No termino de comprender como funcionan este tipo de consultas en Dart, se que es algo similar a como funciona en linq, pero aquí no logro comprenderlo. Así que también os agradecería alguna explicación a nivel más teórico.

Comment: si actualizaste el estado de _selectedCountry con un setState?

Comment: En principio creo que no haría falta y que debería asignarse no?

Comment: si quieres presentar el valor en pantalla tienes que actualizar el estado